# Filter a nested list based on conditions on its elements

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a large ordered list of lists of integers like this

```
set={{3,4,5,6,7,9},{1,2,3,4,5,6},{3,4,5,6,9,10},{3,4,5,6,11,12},{3,4,6,9,11,12},...}
```

and I would like to filter out the nested list based on two conditions. The conditions are two types of shorter nested lists

- pairs of consecutive numbers that are not allowed *anywhere* in the nested list
- pairs of consecutive numbers that *must* occur somewhere in the list

required={{3,4},{5,6},...}

notallowed={{1,2},{9,10},...}

The output in this case would be

```
{{3,4,5,6,7,9},{3,4,5,6,11,12}}
```

Comment: why do you need both `notallowed` and also `allowed`? Would not just using `notallowed` be enought to remove those unwanted?

Comment: No because allowed must be there all present. I can remove all notallowed but that does not guarantee there are all alowed (can be {3,4} but not {5,6}).

Comment: For your use case, what would the maximum integer be? Are the allowed and disallowed sets always pairs of consecutive numbers? Are your sublists always ordered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SequencePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html) -- if it returns a nonempty list, then the given sublist is present:

```
(
set
 // Select[Length@SequencePosition[#, Alternatives @@ notallowed, 1] == 0 &]
 // Select@Function[list, 
       Length@SequencePosition[list, #, 1] > 0 & /@ allowed // Apply@And]
)
```

> ```
> {{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 12}}
> ```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you.